# Concavity in long equation

Tags: calculus

I came across this question:

> Given the function $f(x)=2x^6 + 9x^5 + 10x^4 − 13x − 5$, determine all intervals on which the graph of $f$ is concave up, all intervals where it is concave down, and find all inflection points for $f$.

My guess was that I should use the first derivative to find inflection points and then check the spaces before and after it to know if it's concave up or concave down. I've tried but my results don't make any sense... Could anyone show the process? I keep getting lost in the huge numbers.

Thanks!

Comment: Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You propose to determine intervals first. Then how will you know the concavity of convexity for each ? Once answered: Finally, was it necessary to have explicited the intervals at first ? ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Once you have one interval, how would do you compute whether it's concave or concave in it ?

Comment: Well I'd check if the second derivative is negative (downward) or positive (upward), right?

Comment: yep. Did you tried ? ( and why exactly do you need the interval to do that ?)